# GKMatchRequest.playergroup=0 not matching to any existing match

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

The Apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/playerGroup
says:
"Setting the playerGroup property to 0 allows the player to be matched into any waiting match."

I don't think this is what is really happening. I have tried a whole bunch of different scenarios for the turn-based match and found that if you set player group to 0, it only finds other players with playerGroup set to zero. It does seem to be matching people based on the playerGroup otherwise.

I guess I was expecting playerGroup=0 to be a kind of "Don't care" when it comes to the different rule sets. That is, I was expecting you could create a game with any rule set you want. Then, if a second player gives the "don't care" option (which would set playerGroup = 0), then it would go ahead an match them with any existing game waiting for a player.

As far as I can tell, it isn't working this way.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if this is (yet another) error in the GC docs, or (yet another) bug in GC operation. As an experiment, what happens if you set the playerGroup bit mask to all 1's? Will it match anyone, or will it only match others that also have all 1's?

Comment: I just tried that and with no success. I haven't used any of my support incidents this year and my year is up in April, so I am going to see if they have a workaround.